# Encoding doesn't take affect Reading word document C#

Tags: c#, office-interop

Trying to read unicode characters from a word document but getting symbols (????).

Here my code :

```
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
             object enc = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoEncoding.msoEncodingEUCJapanese; 
            object path = @"C:\Users\file.doc"
            object readOnly = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss,
                ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref enc, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            string totaltext = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                totaltext += " \r\n " + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine(totaltext);
            }
           // Console.WriteLine(totaltext);
            docs.Close();
            word.Quit();
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a matter of your `Console.WriteLine` not supporting the relevant characters? Have you tried dumping out the individual UTF-16 code points?

Comment: how can I do that Mr Jon ?

Comment: Iterate over each character in the string and write it out: `foreach (char c in x) { Console.WriteLine("{0:X4}", (int) c); }`

Comment: I am getting different codes that mean what you mention in the first comment that the problem in the Console.Writeline?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. But you should look up the results you get against http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/

Comment: You are right Mr Jon the codes are right if I wrote the characters into a text file I should be fine ?

Comment: Well, if you write them out using an encoding which supports all the characters - e.g. UTF-8. I'll add an answer to that effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the comments, it sounds like the problem may well just be with `Console.WriteLine`.

Try writing to a file instead:

```
// This will use Encoding.UTF8 by default.
using (var writer = File.CreateText("test.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then open the file in Notepad, specifying UTF-8 as the encoding, and I suspect you'll see everything correctly.